# Compute stable/unstable/center manifold for nonlinear system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Given a system: $\dot{x_1} = x_1(x_n - \phi(x))$, $\dot{x_n} = x_n(x_(n-1)-\phi(x))$ where $\phi(x) = x_1x_2 + x_2x_3 + \ldots + x_nx_1$. Let $S_n = \left\{x\in R^n: \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i = 1, x_i\geq 0\ \forall\  i = 1,\ldots, n\right\}$.

(a) For $n=2$, find all the stable, unstable and center manifolds for each equilibrium of the system on $S_2$, provided they exist.

(b) For $n=3$, find all the stable, unstable and center manifolds for each equilibrium of the system on $S_2$, provided they exist.

**My attempt:** For part (a), I was able to solve for the equilibrium points on $S_2$, which are: $(x_1, x_2) = (0,1), (1,0), (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$. Now, at the equilibrium point $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$, the matrix $Df((1,0))$ and $Df((0,1))$ of the corresponding linearized system all have unique eigenvalue = 0 (double multiplicity). So $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$ is not hyperbolic, which means the center manifold don't exist at these points. So we're left with finding the stable/unstable manifold. But since the eigenvalue is just $0$, based on definition of stable/unstable subspace, I think neither stable manifold or unstable manifold at $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$ exists? But this really contradicts to the center manifold theorem:P

Also, based on the definition, in this particular case, I think the stable manifold = center manifold must happen, as otherwise I don't know how to solve directly for both stable manifold and center manifold (both requires us to find the polynomial $h(y)$ such that $x = h(y)$ satisfies the DEs system, so we should always have the same $h(y)$ for center manifold and stable manifold via this method). Can someone please help clarify for me the method for finding BOTH stable and center manifold?

Assume that there exists such a stable/unstable manifold. Then we have: $\frac{dx_2}{dx_1} = \frac{1-2x_2}{1-2x_1}$. Thus, by separation of variables, we get: $\frac{ln|1-2x_2|}{2} = \frac{ln|1-2x_2|}{2} + C$ where C is some constant. This implies $|1-2x_2| = D|1-2x_1| $. At the point $(0,1)$, we would have: $2x_2 - 1 = D(1-2x_1)$, so $x_2 = \frac{D(1-2x_1)+1}{2}$ with $x_2(0) = 0$ and $x_2'(0) = 0$. Plugging the first condition in, we get $D=-1$ (contradiction since $D>0$), so there doesn't exist a stable manifold at $(0,1)$.  Similarly, at $(1,0)$, we would have: $1-2x_2 = D(2x_1-1)$ with $x_1(0) = 0$ and $x_1'(0) = 0$. The first condition implies $D=-1$, which is wrong. Thus there also doesn't exist a stable manifold at $(1,0)$.

Comment: Center  manifold exists *exactly* when you have non-hyperbolic steady state. If equilibrium is hyperbolic, then it has only stable and unstable manifolds (and only one of them might coincide with equilibrium itself).

Comment: @Evgeny: You're ccorrec:) I messed up on my computation of $Df((0,1))$ and $Df((1,0))$. They all have 2 eigenvalues: $0$ and $1$. But using the trick that I used above, why couldn't I find the valid equation of $x_2$ in terms of $x_1$? Can you please help show how you can find the unstable manifold for the eigenvalue $1$, and center manifold for eigenvalue $0$?

Comment: In this case for finding the unstable manifold, the only method I know is to set $y=h(x)$ with I.C $h(0) = 0$ and $h'(0) = 0$, and then plugging into one of the DE after using the chain rule on the RHS to find the polynomial $h(x)$. For center manifold, let $x=h(y)$ and do the same process. Is that the only way?

Comment: I'll try to take a careful look at your problem when I'll have enough time. But you should be careful: $h'(0) = 0$ iff invariant manifold $y - h(x)$ is parallel to $Ox$ axis. And it might be not the case in your problem, check eigenvectors.

Comment: @Evgeny: yeah I had thought about that initial condition, but the key failure is in the I.C $h(0) = 0$, which is very correct unfortunately:(

Comment: @Evgeny: sorry, I made another mistake:P The points $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ are both non-hyperbolic since they have 2 eigenvalues $0$ and $1$, so there is only a center manifold at these equilibriums. For $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$, since this is hyperbolic, there must be one stable (aka, find $h(y)$ such that $x=h(y)$ satisfying the system) and one unstable manifold (aka, find $g(y)$ such that $x=g(y)$ satisfying the system).

Comment: @Evgeny: did you get a chance to work on the stable/unstable manifold? Can you clarify on whether the conditions $h'(0) = 0$ and $h'(0) =  1$ are correct for the equilibrium points $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$, respectively?

Comment: Write down how your system looks like for $n = 2$ and $n=3$ (add this to your question and notify me). Because I tried to do this, but $S_2$ doesn't happen to be invariant manifold and hence question is meaningless.

Comment: Oh, you've already written case $n=2$. Yeah, now that makes sense.

Comment: @Evgeny: apology for this late reply. $S_2$, $S_3$ and $S_4$ are all invariant manifolds:)